# RAID0 SSD array write speed and multithreading

Tags: raid, raid-0, threads, multi-threaded

I have a RAID0 array of 20 SSD disks and each SSD has a max write speed of 530 MB/s.
The PCIexpress controller is 8x.

The array is mapped to a virtual disk (D) formatted with NTFS in Windows 10

I was expecting to have write speeds of 7,7 GB/s (PCIExpress bottleneck that reduces the 10 GB/s of the array 20*500MB/s) in my C# application, but the max I can reach is 2,5 GB/S with one thread. Are my assumptions completely wrong?

Also I've notices a thing:
If I have a thread writing 127 MB files on the array I have an average write speed of 2,5 GB/s, with two threads the average write speed goes down to 1,8 GB/s each.
What could be the problem with multiple threads accessing the RAID array?

My code, it uses OpenFileNoBuff class for unbuffered writes from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/sequential-file-programming-patterns-and-performance-with-net/)

```
class Program
{

        const int SIZE = 134184960;
        static string Folder = @"D:\Test";
        static int BlockSize = 65536  ;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var watchTotal = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
            Thread ConsumerThread1 = new Thread(SaveFramesOnDisk);
            Thread ConsumerThread2 = new Thread(SaveFramesOnDisk);

            ConsumerThread1.Start(Folder + "1");
            ConsumerThread2.Start(Folder + "2");

            ConsumerThread1.Join();
            ConsumerThread2.Join();

            watchTotal.Stop();

            long elapsedMs = watchTotal.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            long elapsedS = elapsedMs / 1000;
            Console.WriteLine("TOTAL ELAPSED s: " + elapsedS);
            double gbWritten = 134184960f * 1200 / 1073741824f;
            double avgWriteSpeed = Math.Round(gbWritten / elapsedS,3);
            Console.WriteLine("Avg. write speed GB/s: " + avgWriteSpeed);
        }

        static void SaveFramesOnDisk(object f) 
        {
            //Write 600 frame - 30 seconds acquisition
            for (int i = 0; i < 600; i++)
            {
                
                byte[] data = new byte[SIZE];

                Directory.CreateDirectory(Convert.ToString(f));
                
                //var watchFrame = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
                FileStream fs = null;
                OpenFileNoBuff of = null;

                of = new OpenFileNoBuff();
                fs = of.openStream(Path.Combine(Convert.ToString(f), DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HHmmss-fffffff") + ".raw"),
                                    FileMode.Create,
                                    FileAccess.Write,
                                    FileShare.None,
                                    true,
                                    false,
                                    BlockSize);

                //SafeFileHandle handle = File.OpenHandle(Path.Combine(Convert.ToString(f), DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HHmmss-fffffff") + ".raw"), 
                //                                                           FileMode.Create, 
                //                                                           FileAccess.Write, 
                //                                                           FileShare.None, 
                //                                                           FileOptions.Asynchronous, 
                //                                                           SIZE);

                //fs = new FileStream(Path.Combine(Convert.ToString(f), DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HHmmss-fffffff") + ".raw"), FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, 1);
                //fs = new FileStream(handle, FileAccess.Write, 0);

                fs.SetLength(SIZE);

                fs.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                
                //fs.Flush();
                of.closeStream();
                fs.Close();
                fs.Dispose();
                //watchFrame.Stop();

                //long elapsedFrameMs = watchFrame.ElapsedMilliseconds;

                //Console.WriteLine("elapsedMs for " + i + " write: " + elapsedFrameMs);
                //double time = (double)elapsedFrameMs / 1000;
                //double size = 134184960f / 1073741824f;
                //double speed = size / time;
                //Console.WriteLine("Write speed " + speed + " GB/s");
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Check CPU load by cores. One core can be fully loaded with 1 thread and it might be a bottleneck.

Comment: I see only a spike on one core, but the load doesn't seem too high
Here's the screenshot https://imgur.com/a/Rjn5Dl6

Comment: I don't know how your app is writing data (block size, total write size, duration, queue depth). I assume with 8 threads and QD=16 you'll get approx 6GB/s on large >64k blocks. Test the storage with diskspd to check, wether the issue caused by underlying storage or access patterns of C# app. P.S. single thread cannot fully utilize the full potential of flash storage.

Comment: At the moment i just have two threads writing on the volume
The RAID array has these characteristics

Raid Set Name: Raid Set # 000;
Volume Capacity: 159999.9GB (0x48C2720000);
SCSI Ch/Id/Lun: 0/0/0;
Raid Level: Raid 0;
Stripe Size: 64KBytes;
Block Size: 512Bytes;
Member Disks: 20;
Cache Mode: Write Back;
Write Protection: Disabled;
Volume Encryption: Non-Encrypted.

I am trying to understand how diskspd works to test sequential writes, but still can't figure that out

Comment: diskspd -c50G -b256k -t8 -o16 -si -w100 -Sh -ag -d60 D:\testfile.tmp

Comment: as example, where RAID0 volume is D:\

Comment: This is the output...could you help me interpret it?
https://pastebin.com/bQ2knTww

Comment: I've understood that 
I'm writing a 50 GiB file on D:
with 8 threads, each one writing 50GiB / 8 why?

I don't know what is the o16 parameter, outstanding I/O operations ?
Block size is 256K what is that? The portion of file written at each iteration?

Comment: Yes, 50GB file. You can change this value as any others. Based on output, the storage throughput is approx 4.2 GB/s, not bad, but also not excellent. Try to disable write back cache on RAID0, because all writes goes firstly to cache.  Your application use 64k blocks, so change the -b256k parameter to -b64k. P.S. Here is article with diskspd bechmarking example, might be helpfull - https://www.starwindsoftware.com/blog/benchmarking-samsung-nvme-ssd-960-evo-m-2

Comment: I've changed the block size (64K) and write speed reduced
I've changed also the Volume Cache Mode from "Write Back" to "Write Through" and this is the result https://pastebin.com/xfJtyJt1
I thought for me it was better the Write Back. I can't find a way to disable cache

Comment: I've read the article
You meant to disable caching in diskspd, removing the -Sh param, tried it but the performance got worse 2158,53 MiB/s

Comment: I meant to disbale write-back cache on RAID-controller (not Volume Cache). -Sh parameter in diskspd skips any Windows RAM-buffering for I/O.

Comment: Done it, but i get worse performance.

It is as it says in the manual of my controller 
Disk Write Cache Mode
User can set the “Disk Write Cache Mode” to Auto, Enabled, or Disabled. “Enabled” increases speed, “Disabled” increases reliability.